# How can I optimize multiple inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, inner-join

I have 2 tables (SQL Server 2008): Documents and Fields.

**Documents:**

```
Id  (PK)
Some-Others-Columns
```

**Fields:**

```
Id  (PK) 
DocumentId  (FK to Documents) 
Name
Value
```

Every document has 80+ fields assigned. I have to select a table, where every row is a document + some specific fields (not 80+, only some of the fields).

I have T-SQL code that works extremely slow for big tables, how can I optimize that?

```
SELECT f1.Value AS 'f1', f2.Value AS 'f2', f3.Value AS 'f3', f4.Value AS 'f4', f5.Value AS 'f5', f6.Value AS 'f6', d.PartyId, d.CreationDate
FROM dbo.Fields AS f WITH (NOLOCK) 
  INNER JOIN dbo.Fields AS f1 ON f.Id = f1.Id 
  INNER JOIN dbo.Documents AS d ON f1.DocumentId = d.Id 
  INNER JOIN dbo.Fields AS f2 ON d.Id = f2.DocumentId
  INNER JOIN dbo.Fields AS f3 ON d.Id = f3.DocumentId
  INNER JOIN dbo.Fields AS f4 ON d.Id = f4.DocumentId
  INNER JOIN dbo.Fields AS f5 ON d.Id = f5.DocumentId
  INNER JOIN dbo.Fields AS f6 ON d.Id = f6.DocumentId

WHERE
    (f1.Name = 'Some-Name-1')
AND (f2.Name = 'Some-Name-2')
AND (f3.Name = 'Some-Name-3')
AND (f4.Name = 'Some-Name-4')
AND (f5.Name = 'Some-Name-5')
AND (f6.Name = 'Some-Name-6')
```

Please, help me to optimize this query

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if a pivot will perform better, you'd need to then join this back with documents to get your other document fields.  My syntax might be a bit off(You can setup an SQL Fiddle with two tables and sample rows inserted if you want me to fix it: http://sqlfiddle.com/)

```
SELECT DocumentId, 
[Some-Name-1], [Some-Name-2], [Some-Name-3], [Some-Name-4], [Some-Name-5],[Some-Name-6]
FROM (
  Select f.DocumentId, f.Name, f.Value
  FROM dbo.Fields AS f 
  INNER JOIN dbo.Documents AS d ON f.DocumentId = d.Id ) as SourceTable
PIVOT
(
  SUM(Value)
  FOR Name IN ([Some-Name-1], [Some-Name-2], [Some-Name-3], [Some-Name-4], [Some-Name-5],[Some-Name-6])
) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: Ah yes, or `d.Id`.  This is why I usually have more verbose primary key names of d.DocumentId.

Answer (score 1):

you can use ctrl+l to see the execution plan and what is taking the longest time to execute. You most likely want an index on ID and name for the fields table and on ID on the documents table

Comment: Execution plan tells me that if I create index then excution plan will be 17% optimized. But may be the whole approach how I collect data for my query is wrong?

Comment: @Andrew 1) you're taking some risks using (NOLOCK) already.  2) This table structure is something I have been victim to and am not a fan of it, if it can be avoided.  It makes alot of things very difficult.  For one, all of your f.Value's are of the same type.  So you lose the ability to constrain types for different fields.  3) What you are doing with this query is called a pivot.  SQL has a pivot command, but it might be easier to perform the pivot somewhere else.  Is this data going into Excel or some application?  Instead of flattening it out with the query, have your application do that?

Answer (score 1):

The high performance cost comes from having so many joins.
Why not get a recordset of the "fields" of the desired document?
Maybe I didn't get it right...

```
SELECT value 
FROM Documents AS d 
INNER JOIN Fields as f ON d.Id=f.DocumentId 
WHERE (f.Name="Name1" or f.Name="Name2" or.. etc);
```

There you should have a recordset of all the "Value" columns in the fields of the Document

If you NEED the values forming columns, you should do it after the first query

Comment: Agreed - you don't need all those repeated table joins - just join once. You will get a 'document' record for every 'hit' but that might not be a big deal. What you've built is a entity attribute database model. Some people hate it some people love it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT f1.Value AS 'f1', f2.Value AS 'f2', f3.Value AS 'f3', f4.Value AS 'f4', f5.Value AS 'f5', f6.Value AS 'f6', d.PartyId, d.CreationDate
FROM dbo.Fields AS f WITH (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN (SELECT Id, DocumentId, Value FROM dbo.Fields WHERE Name='Some-Name-1') AS f1 
    ON f.Id = f1.Id 
INNER JOIN (SELECT Id, CreationDate, PartyId  FROM dbo.Documents) AS d
    ON f1.DocumentId = d.Id 
INNER JOIN (SELECT Id, DocumentId, Value FROM dbo.Fields WHERE Name='Some-Name-2') AS f2
    ON d.Id = f2.DocumentId
INNER JOIN (SELECT Id, DocumentId, Value FROM dbo.Fields WHERE Name='Some-Name-3') AS f3
    ON d.Id = f3.DocumentId
INNER JOIN (SELECT Id, DocumentId, Value FROM dbo.Fields WHERE Name='Some-Name-4') AS f4
    ON d.Id = f4.DocumentId
INNER JOIN (SELECT Id, DocumentId, Value FROM dbo.Fields WHERE Name='Some-Name-5') AS f5
    ON d.Id = f5.DocumentId
INNER JOIN (SELECT Id, DocumentId, Value FROM dbo.Fields WHERE Name='Some-Name-6') AS f6
    ON d.Id = f6.DocumentId
```